Longer time to start when warm and 3/6 cylinder misfire
I have a Lexus LS500 2018 with 47k miles. It has two issues:

When engine is warm (if left for 45 minutes to 4 hours), it takes 3-4 seconds longer to start and some times I see some dark smoke from the exhaust for a bit. I have changed spark plugs and maintenance for the injectors but no change and mechanics gave up on this but it still bugs me.
I got check engine light two time. I have techstream so I could extract the data list at the time of misfire (it is cylinder misfire - cylinder 6 and 3). LT trim especially for bank 2 is a bit high and does not cycle (+7%). I have attached the full data list.

Last year, the car had a from end accident and had to replace radiator, condenser, fan, and air intake tank (it had a small crack). So I am thinking there is another leak somewhere that was not noticed but I am not sure that can be deduced by the data list. I would appreciate any comment as I have taken it to many mechanics but each is telling me replace something different without really having proper diagnosis behind their recommendations.









Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't think I'd worry too much about your LTFT. The LTFT do not fluctuate very much. The system adjusts them to get to a proper O2 reading, then uses the STFT to modify them. You'll see the STFT's adjust rather quickly and erratically (seemingly). The LTFT takes a lot of time for it to have movement. Also, 7% isn't a huge amount of adjustment for B2. Not a huge difference between B1 and B2, as well.
